# PIG - trying to find max of group of months in table

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

[image]

The above image represents generate statement below and describe too

```
  D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0 AS time, $1 AS perf_temp_count;

  DUMP D;
  DESCRIBE D;
```

MY question is curretnly the above is grouped my Month and Hour(miltary time) and  i am trying to find the max number next to it per each month. 1 through 12, right now i am just showing the month, hours, and numbers.

My expected out put is

```
  (1, 4) 9
   ....
   remaning months
   ....
  (12, 3) 10
```

Where this again descibes ( Month, hour), Max count

Comment: try E = FOREACH D GENERATE time,MAX(perf_temp_count);

Comment: alread had tried that. could not infer the matching function for org.pig.builitin.MAX as ,multiple or none of them fit, please use an explicit cast

Comment: tried that too no luck

Comment: it seems like I can't perform MAX after count, :/ idk why The aggregation wont cary over :/ maybe group by again?? i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B = GROUP A BY (month, hour);
C= FOREACH B GENERATE group as time,COUNT(A.temp) as cnt
X = GROUP C By time;
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE group, MAX(C.cnt) as mcount;
```

I have no idea why, but Agrregating(MAX) right after another aggregate(COUNT) is a problem or I am not refrencing the names correctly.